# Очистка истории переходов

Tags: java, android, android-intent, activity

Доброго времени суток!

Ситуация такая: В приложении есть 2 activity: MainActivity и NotifActivity.
Бредкаст подписан на изменения системы (не суть). При этом, приложение находится постоянно в "закрытом" состоянии (т.е., если его открыть или запустить из диспетчера - вылетает MainActivity)

Так вот, в какой-то момент, бредкаст кидает нотификацию пользователю. Пользователь нажимает на нее и переходит на NotifActivity. Пользователь может свернуть приложение кнопкой назад, и, развернув приложение снова, окажется снова в NotifActivity, здесь все работает как надо. Но если человек нажмет на кнопку CloseButton, расположенную в этой активити, приложение закрывается, НО при следующей загрузке приложения пользователь уже попадает на MainActivity, при этом, не имея возможности вернуться в NotifActivity.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой код должен висеть на моей кнопке CloseButton?

Comment: Может проще хранить где-то на диске значение, запускать или не запускать NotifActivity?

Comment: не.. надо именно так, как описал )